# Minifying in visual studio 2019

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I installed the nuget package related to bundlerMinifier in Visual Studio 2019, but when I select the file related to css,html and etc. for minifying, there is no option related to minifition and bundlre. How can i do it .Thank you for your help

Comment: With right click on files: [link to GitHub](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier).

Comment: I had the same issues and I just found out thattThis extension is integrated only with Visual Studio 2015 & 2017